# How to link my Apps on Android Market with other Apps

Tags: android, google-play, launching-application

I have developed 4 android Apps and published in Android Market(each apps signed with different private keys but uploaded through only one gmail Account). when i Opened the app details page from Android Market site, it doesn't shows my other 3 Applications under "More from developer".

This happened for all my 4 Application.

So what should be done in order to have my other Android Applications to come under "More from developer"??

Comment: Signing with different keys doesn't effect if the apps appear under "more from developer" page. Are you sure that you are uploading applications from single Android market publisher account?

Comment: Yes, I have uploaded applications from single Android Market publisher Account.And i have get rid of that problem by signing the Apps with same key. Now i got my other apps visible under "more from developer". Thanks for your reply..

Comment: Well that's interesting. I have two apps and both are signed with different keys and they show up on "show more from developer". It looks like they have changed something recently then....

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a [documented `Intent` syntax](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html#marketintent) for that (`http://market.android.com/search?q=pub:<Developer Name> or market://search?q=pub:<Developer Name>`).

Comment: He is not trying to do search for app from himself. but instead he is confused how to upload apps so that its visible inside "more from Developer" section.